# Nextjs13 Open alert before changing URL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, navigation

In previous Nextjs, it was possible to prevent from the user to pop out with the `'next/route'` module.
Now it is not possible because we need to use `'next/navigation'`.

How can I run a function before user goes to a different route, or pressing the 'back' button in the browser with the new nextjs?